# ExtJS 5 Menu Widget

Tags: extjs, grid, widget, xtype

Is there an xtype menu widget in Sencha 5? I want to popup a menu on click of an icon in a column of Ext.grid.Panel. Something like belo. Or, do I have to create a custom widget?

```
{
            text: 'Menu',
            width: 105,
            xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
            dataIndex: 'menu',
            widget: {
                width: 90,
                xtype: 'menu',
                items: [{                        
                  text: 'regular item 1'        
                },{
                  text: 'regular item 2'
                },{
                  text: 'regular item 3'  
                },
                handler: function(btn) {
                    var rec = menu.getWidgetRecord();
                    ///...
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: i need to add menu in my grid please help me (i am new in extjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different approach is needed: Configure your widget as button with `menu` config option. This way the button will be displayed in the grid column and clicking on it will open the menu.

Comment: any idea on how to get grid record in menuItem handler?

Comment: IT may be possible to pass the record as a custom property to the button or the menu while creating them.

Comment: yes, Thanks! what I am doing now. While I am at it, if I were to change the iconCls of Button in widgetcolumn per grid row, what is the the best way to go about it? Currently, I am playing with widgetcolumns, renderer function to change widgetcolumns' button iconCls